# Why browser scale crashes the div fixed css width?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="parent">
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
div.parent {

 width: 100px;

}
div.parent div {

   width: 25px;
   float: left
}
</style>
```

the problem is that when the browser scales, or some users have a smaller monitor, the child div(thats is 25px) are getted down to the next div line, there also may be images, I've tried to set them fixed width and height, but still the div size changes when the user changes the page zoom, why this happens?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yep, a demo of what's happening would be useful.  With the above, the `div`s shouldn't wrap - is this all of the html that's needed to cause the problem, or have you oversimplified it?

Comment: What browser and what other CSS is applied such as paddings, margins, etc.

Comment: you have 4 child divs with 25px in a parent div with a 100px with, so I'm guessing you are using some margin/padding in your child's div, which is will be greater than 100px. but please provide a fiddle

Comment: @JamesThorpe: plus with literally just the above, the `<div>`s will be invisible, so it’ll be difficult to tell if they’re wrapping or not.

Comment: @Paul That too!  You _could_ see with developer tools if you were looking...